# How can I combined Realm Results<> into a single Result<> set?

Tags: swift, realm

The model is as follows (simplified example)

```
class Parent: Object {
   let id = ObjectId()
   let name: String = "some name"

   let children = List<Child>
}

class Child: Object {
   let id = ObjectId()
   let name: String = "some name"

}
```

How can I get all the parents children back as a since results set ?  It seems odd to define the `var all` as a `LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<Results<Parent>, List<Child>>.Elements>>`

```
extension Child {

   var all: Results<Child> {
      let parents = realm.objects(Parent.self)

      // Returns LazyMapSequence<Results<Parent>, List<Child>>
      let children = parents.map({$0.children})

      // Returns LazySequence<FlattenSequence<LazyMapSequence<Results<Parent>, List<Child>>.Elements>>
      let all = children.joined()

      return all
   }
}
```

Comment: Coerce to an array?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a inverse relationship from `Child` to `Parent`:

```
// in Child
let parents = LinkingObjects(fromType: Parent.self, property: "children")
```

Then, you can get all the children, and filter by whether they have parents:

```
realm.objects(Child.self).filter("parents.@count > 0")
```

This will give you a `Result<Child>`.